# Raw characters coming in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, hyperlink, continuous-integration

I have a strange problem in codeigniter. All my URLs showing random characters in URL after the page loads up.

For example www.example.com/home#.UhGoaX_8vFk. Characters including # sign (#.UhGoaX_8vFk) automatically comes when any link is clicked.

If anybody has any idea, please share to save my life.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some third party javascript loading on your page? like any pixel  or an exit pop or something

Comment: Show your controller and view. Then we are able to see what happen.

Comment: These are is not "random characters"...

Comment: Hanky Panky right, this issue about including js. Check your including js files.

Comment: @Hanky Panky and Bora ... Thank you so much. You are right. At the bottom of the page, I have added addthis JS Code. I have removed the code and got the clean URL. Now what is the best place to put these JS includes because in my experience, JS files need to be loaded after the body tag ends.. Any views?

Comment: YOu are using "addthis" third party code on your page, so please go any configure  "addthis" code, not display in url.